# синхронизация двух баз данных openServer и MAMP

Tags: openserver, mamp

работаю над одним проектом на разных компьютерах Windows (openServer) и Mac (MAMP).
Есть ли возможность синхронизировать базы данных  OpenServer и MAMP?
Или какие есть варианты ? Проект находится на GitHub.